# Expired time in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I use RabbitMQ for delayed message processing. For the implementation I use two queues - WorkQueue and WaitQueue. At first, messages are putted into WaitQueue with some expired time. After this time it's should go to WorkQueue. But it doesn't work.
If I put 2 messages: with expired time 1 minute and 10 minutes. In this case both messages delivered after 10 minutes. Is it a correct behavior?

Queues creation:

```
channel.queueDeclare(Config.getInstance().getRabbitmqWorkQueue(), true, false, false, null);
channel.queueBind(Config.getInstance().getRabbitmqWorkQueue(), Config.getInstance().getRabbitmqWorkExchange(), "");
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", Config.getInstance().getRabbitmqWorkExchange());
channel.exchangeDeclare(Config.getInstance().getRabbitmqWaitExchange(), "direct");
channel.queueDeclare(Config.getInstance().getRabbitmqWaitQueue(), true, false, false, args);
channel.queueBind(Config.getInstance().getRabbitmqWaitQueue(), Config.getInstance().getRabbitmqWaitExchange(), "");
```

Messages sending:

```
channel.basicPublish(Config.getInstance().getRabbitmqWaitExchange(), "",
    new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
    .deliveryMode(1)
    .expiration(String.valueOf(delay))
    .build(), ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(event.getId()).array());
```

Comment: Let's see some code. It's possible that you're setting the time out on the queue instead of the message.

Comment: I attached code of queues creation and sending messages.

Comment: Few things: I don't see your code for setting the value of `delay` which controls your message's timeout. I suggest taking the property `Builder` call into a separate line with its own object instantiated. Use your debugger to break on the `BasicProperties` instance and check your values. I'm guessing you have a bug in the code that sets `delay`

Comment: I don't think so because I tested queues with RebbitMQ Management Plugin (admin panel) and expiration was set correctly. For example one message with expiration 2591999989 and other with expiration 59990. Thus, I waited second message around 20 minutes (that more then 59990ms of course) and it still was in WaitQueue.

Comment: Hmm. That kind of observation suggests that there's something wrong with the server or there's some configuration at fault. What version of RabbitMQ are you running? And I would suggest posting this question and info on the product support boards.

Comment: RabbitMQ 3.3.5, Erlang 17 under Arch Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While consumers never see expired messages, only when expired messages reach the head of a queue will they actually be discarded (or dead-lettered). (c) [documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl-caveats)